# AWS ECS FARGATE between RDS TimeOut

Tags: amazon-ecs

We set up servers on 2 different platforms, Aws ECS and Digitalocens.
When we do our mobile application tests, there is no problem with api requests made with the digitaloceans platform.

However, we are having problems with the api communication with the environment established on the Aws ecs platform.

Summary of the Problem: Containers in Aws Ecs work for a while, then timeout after a few minutes after connection with RDS database. During this time, AWS ECS Service is at RUNNING. Service Crash not happening

Comment: timeout changed from 60 to 3600

Comment: Nodejs version change from 12 to 18

Comment: Are there database queries happening that you expect to take a long time? There aren't nearly enough details in your question for anyone to help you at this point. Also, please find the "Edit" button on your question and use that to add further details instead of adding them as comments.

Comment: As a result of the research, we determined that the problem was caused by sequelize.thx